# How do I delete particular XML Attributes?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I have an XML string stored in SQL. The program that inserts the XML doesn't tag all the objects inside.

Example of string:

```
<XMLInfo Sample1="1234" Sample2="1234" Sample3="1234" Sample4="1234" />
```

I need to delete the `sample2` item completely. Other things complicating this is that `Sample2` may not be followed by `sample3` every time and `sample2` does not have a fixed length.

Comment: What do you mean by "_stored in SQL_"? SQL stands for Structured Query Language; you can't store anything in a language. If you meant a Microsoft SQL Server database -- what version? What is the table definition?

Comment: There are ways to delete the attribute with name `Sample2` regardless of where in the attribute list it is or if the other attributes are there or not. But it is done differently depending on what DBMS you are using (SQL Server, Oracle, ...).

Comment: @Eriksson I have the data stored in a MSSQL 2008 database. I am attempting to perform the edit using Mgmt Studio

Comment: Those aren't called variables. Those are XML Attributes. Also, what is the data type of the column the XML is stored in?

Answer (score 2):

**SQL Server**:

```
update test set data.modify('delete XMLInfo/@Sample2');
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6aa37/1)

**PostgreSQL** (I think there's no xml parsing/modifying functions, but there extensions):

```
create or replace function remove_attrib(data xml, attr text)
returns xml
as
$$
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
r = ET.fromstring(data)
del r.attrib[attr]
return ET.tostring(r)
$$ language plpython3u;

update test set data = remove_attrib(data, 'Sample2');
```